# How to make an inpit affect on function's parameter? python, doesn't work for me while I'm trying to make a boot

Tags: python, function, input, parameters

```
def market_list(user_request):
    fixed_list_option_1 = customer_products_string.split(' ', )
    if user_request == 1:
        return fixed_list_option_1
    elif user_request == 2:
        return fixed_list_option_1.count


customer_products_string = "pizza,apple"
user_request = input("What is your request? (insert the number of the command) : ")
print(market_list(user_request))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Input seems string here. That's why you should use user_request == "1" or "2" or int(input("...")).

```
def market_list(user_request):
    fixed_list_option_1 = customer_products_string.split(',', )
    if user_request == "1":
        return fixed_list_option_1
    elif user_request == "2":
        return len(fixed_list_option_1)

customer_products_string = "pizza,apple"
user_request = input("What is your request? (insert the number of the command) : ")
print(market_list(user_request))
```